# avatar for Microsoft Chat Bot Framework

Tags: chatbot

I am hoping this will be an easy question to answer.

I have a bot up and running nicely using the Microsoft Bot Framework but cannot figure out how to make the avatar of the bot display next to the text it sends back. I have googled this and to my amazement nobody seems to be taking about it.

I had to resort to using Adaptive Cards but I know this is not the correct method. Can anyone advise on how to do this?

Thanks,
-Mike

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the webchat client, no this is not configurable like you describe unless you do your own customisations.